# Manipulate JavaScript Array

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I hope you can help me. How to convert this flat JavaScript array, from:

```
[
    {"state":"First State","district":"First District","local_district_id":1,"zone_id":117,"center_id":"A","center_name":"Voting Center First"},
    {"state":"First State","district":"First District","local_district_id":2,"zone_id":117,"center_id":"B","center_name":"Voting Center Second"},
    {"state":"First State","district":"First District","local_district_id":6,"zone_id":117,"center_id":"C","center_name":"Voting Center Third"},
]
```

into a nested array, like so:

```
[{
    "state": "First State",
    "children": [{
        "district_name": "First District",
        "children": [{
            "local_district_id": 1,
            "zone_id": 117,
            "center_id": "A",
            "center_name": "Voting Center Name First",
        }, {
            "local_district_id": 2,
            "zone_id": 117,
            "center_id": "B",
            "center_name": "Voting Center Name Second",
        }, {
            "local_district_id": 6,
            "zone_id": 117,
            "center_id": "C",
            "center_name": "Voting Center Name Third",
        }]
    }]
}]
```

Comment: I sense there will be lots of looping involved.

Comment: A couple of underscore `groupBy`'s ought to do the trick. Would you consider that?

Comment: Yes, I am considering anything that works. I've tried so many loops, but it seems that my JS loop skills aren't anywhere near solving this sort of problem.

Comment: Even though Jonathan's answer did the trick, I would appreciate seeing an underscore approach to this as I tried it yesterday and couldn't figure out how to use groupBy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this to get this working with a single loop. Not the prettiest function but it gets the job done without a lot of extra overhead.

```
<script>
var original = [
    {"state":"First State","district":"First District","local_district_id":1,"zone_id":117,"center_id":"A","center_name":"Voting Center First"},
    {"state":"Second State","district":"First District","local_district_id":2,"zone_id":117,"center_id":"B","center_name":"Voting Center Second"},
    {"state":"First State","district":"First District","local_district_id":6,"zone_id":117,"center_id":"C","center_name":"Voting Center Third"},
];

var statesUsed = {};
var districtsUsed = {};
var newArray = [];
var stateIndex = 0;
var districtIndex = 0;

for (var i=0,l=original.length;i<l;i++) {
    var state = original[i].state;
    var district = original[i].district;
    var local_district_id = original[i].local_district_id;
    var zone_id = original[i].zone_id;
    var center_id = original[i].center_id;
    var center_name = original[i].center_name;

    if (statesUsed[state] == undefined) {
        statesUsed[state] = stateIndex;
        stateIndex++;
        newArray.push({state : state, children : []});
    }

    districtsUsed[state] = (districtsUsed[state] == undefined) ? {} : districtsUsed[state];

    if (districtsUsed[state][district] == undefined) {
        newArray[statesUsed[state]].children.push({district_name : district, children : []});
        districtsUsed[state][district] = newArray[statesUsed[state]].children.length - 1;
    }

    newArray[statesUsed[state]].children[districtsUsed[state][district]].children.push({
          local_district_id : local_district_id,
          zone_id : zone_id,
          center_id : center_id,
          center_name : center_name
    });


}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Forgot the obvious...but:

```
  JSON = [
    {"state":"First State","district":"First District","local_district_id":1,"zone_id":117,"center_id":"A","center_name":"Voting Center First"},
    {"state":"First State","district":"First District","local_district_id":2,"zone_id":117,"center_id":"B","center_name":"Voting Center Second"},
    {"state":"First State","district":"First District","local_district_id":6,"zone_id":117,"center_id":"C","center_name":"Voting Center Third"},
]
```

messy, but... something like this

```
newObj = {};

for (var i in JSON) {

    if (!newObj.length) {
        newObj.push({'state': JSON[i]['state']})
        delete([JSON[i]['state'])
        newObj[0]['children'] = [JSON[i]]
        continue
    }
    for (var j in newObj) {
        if (newObj[j]['state'] = JSON[i]['state']) {
            delete([JSON[i]['state'])
            newObj[j]['children'].push(JSON[i])
         } else {

        newObj.push({'state': JSON[i]['state']})
        delete([JSON[i]['state'])
        newObj[newObj.length-1]['children'] = [JSON[i]]
         }

    }

}
```

Comment: thanks for the edit! I couldn't for the life of me figure out how to fix that :P

Comment: No problem, just highlight all your code and press the `{}` icon at the top